# Split tree into (almost) equal parts by removing an edge

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a way to split a tree into (almost) equal parts ($\approx \frac{n}{2}$ when $n$ is the number of nodes) by removing exactly one edge?

**EDIT:** Suppose the tree is not a star-graph.

Comment: Depends on the notion of $\approx$. A tree with a root of degree $n-1$ can only be split into $1$ and $n-1$

Comment: This might be an interesting question for a binary tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there is no way to do this. For example a tree could have one node that is connected to all other nodes.

EDIT: Since the question has been updated to rule out the above counter example here is another. Take three copies of any rooted tree with $n$ nodes. Now glue the trees together by identifying all the roots. Now no matter what edge you remove the root node will still be attached to two copies of the original tree. So one part contains at least two thirds of the nodes.

Comment: [Star graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_%28graph_theory%29).

Comment: edited my question

Comment: @TheNotMe Ok then consider a star graph, add one point and connect it to one of the outer points. Just ruling out some counter examples won't really help. You need a condition that enforces the tree to be somewhat balanced somehow.

Comment: I know that the max degree is $\Delta$, that's all.

Comment: @TheNotMe I've updated my answer as well. In general we can construct a graph with maximum degree $\Delta$ such that by removing any single edge there would be one part with at least $\frac{\Delta-1}{\Delta}$ of the nodes.